# Variable with function gives an error ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My skills in jQuery and Javascript are very limited. I do not want to do much with it.
However, I always get an error that I can not explain.

This is my ajax / javascript

```
function eintragen(id){
  $.post('con/essen.php?id='+id, {
   'formular': $("#essen_eintragen").serialize()
  });
}
```

Now my HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h3><b>'.$i.' '.$wochentage[$tag].'</b></h3>
                                    <br>
                                        <u>Kita</u><br>
                                        <textarea style="height:50px;" name="essen" onkeypress="eintragen("kita_'.$tag_java.'")"></textarea>
                                    <hr>
                                        <u>Grundschule</u><br>
                                        <textarea style="height:50px;" name="essen" onkeypress="eintragen("gs_'.$tag_java.'")"></textarea>
                                    <hr>
                                        <u>Sonstiges</u><br>
                                        <textarea style="height:50px;" name="essen" onkeypress="eintragen("son_'.$tag_java.'")"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

If I use this however so, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: What is `onkeypress="eintragen("gs_'.$tag_java.'")"` ? Is something supposed to render it? as it stands the mismatched quotes are not valid.

Comment: While not related to the your problem, this won't work: `onkeypress="eintragen("kita_'.$tag_java.'")"` because the `"` before the `kita_` will end the attribute value of `onkeypress` so it will actually be `onkeypress="eintragen("`

Comment: That is to call every button, the function.

Comment: The `.$tag_java.` bit looks like concatenation of a variable in PHP or similar, is that the case? Its not valid HTML/JavaScript as it stands

Comment: Should it be so? onkeypress="eintragen(kita_'.$tag_java.')"

Comment: Apologize I forgot to say that the HTML area so echo in '' is in the PHP file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not concatenating string properly. Change **onkeypress="eintragen("kita_'.$tag_java.'")"** to **"eintragen('kita_".$tag_java."')"**

```
  <textarea style="height:50px;" name="essen" onkeypress="eintragen("kita_'.$tag_java.'")"></textarea>
```

To

```
<textarea style="height:50px;" name="essen" onkeypress="eintragen('kita_".$tag_java."')"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, now it goes. But now I will give it empty in the food.php $ _POSt ['essen'] or not at all

Comment: Where is food.php?

Comment: Ok, it is not because no value is sent, but the value always comes a click later. So I give for example g one shows it nothing to me. As soon as I then write a g so gg, it shows me the first input. Thus always set back once

food.php: 
$tag = $_GET['id'];
echo 'Hallo '.$_GET['id'].'!'. $_POST['kita_1496268000']  .' Das war essen';